# Retrieve key in JSF from the proper i18n properties file

Tags: jsf-2, properties, internationalization

does somebody know whats wrong with the next method?

```
public static String getMessageBundleString(String key, String localeAcronym) throws MissingResourceException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String messageBundleName = facesContext.getApplication().getMessageBundle();
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(messageBundleName, new Locale(localeAcronym));
        //THE LOCALE OF THIS BUNDLE IS ALWAYS 'es_ES' !!!
    return bundle.getString(key);
}
```

In a **Primefaces/JSF** environment, I want to retrieve a key from the proper i18n properties file.

But it always take it from the **messages_es_ES.properties** file.

Following invocations return **same value** (='Inicio'):

```
getMessageBundleString("home", "es_ES")
getMessageBundleString("home", "uk_UK")

messages_es_ES.properties:
home=Inicio

messages_uk_UK.properties:
home=Home
```

Thanks

Here some of my faces-config.xml content:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <supported-locale>es_ES</supported-locale>
        <supported-locale>uk_UK</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>    
    <message-bundle>cfg.i18n.messages</message-bundle>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>cfg.i18n.messages</base-name>
        <var>msgs</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

Comment: Have you declared your language files into faces-config.xml? Take a look to this post [What is the use of faces-config.xml in JSF 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583038/what-is-the-use-of-faces-config-xml-in-jsf-2)

Comment: Yes, I have some stuff declared in the faces-config.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant works (separating country and language):

```
public static String getMessageBundleString(String key, String language, String country) throws MissingResourceException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String messageBundleName = facesContext.getApplication().getMessageBundle();
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(messageBundleName, new Locale(language, country));
        //Valid ones: "es","ES"; "en","GB"!!!
    return bundle.getString(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this variation?

```
getMessageBundleString("home", "es")
getMessageBundleString("home", "en")
messages_es.properties:
home=Inicio
messages_en.properties:
home=Home
```

Comment: I am not sure that new Locale(String language) accepts character "_".

Comment: [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale%28java.lang.String%29) says "String language" should be - lowercase two-letter ISO-639 code.

Comment: No success with "en", "en_en", "uk", "uk_uk"... :-(

Comment: Your link to the JavaDoc points me to the solution, so I give you one vote. Thanks