# JSF configuration file

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, ajax4jsf

There is a problem with my jsf configuration file. When I open it with Faces Config Editor, the xml file just has Source View, no other Views like Navigation rules, Managed Bean, Component, etc. Do you know why?Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're really using JSF 2, there's no much need to use the faces-config.xml file at least that you want to register i18n bundles, phase listeners or others then there's no much usage of this file. Refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7583038/1065197) to know about it. IMHO it is better to only have the source view and use this file if you really need it to.

Comment: thanks a lot! But I still wanna use the navigation rule in this configuration file, because my project's navigation rule is complicated, it's better to configure it in faces-config.xml. But all the view options disappear except the Source. Do u know how to display those Views? Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you post a sample of this *complicated* navigation rule in order to people could provide guidance to help you solve this riddle.

Comment: Which IDE you are using? And also write down xml code. If possible take backup of your current xml file then delete it. Again recreat the file and then add your stuff in it.