# Unable to deploy and run JSF2.1.6 example on JBOSS4.2

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

**web.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!--  <context-param>
    <description />
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>-->
 <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <description/>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param> 
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value> 
</context-param>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

 <context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
<param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>addUser.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
version="1.2">
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>userBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.test.UserBean
    </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>AddUser</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/AddUser.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/ListUser.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
     </faces-config>
```

**UserBean class**

```
  package com.test;

  public class UserBean{

private int id;
    private String name;

   //Action method to add user
   public String addUser() {

return "success";
    }   
   public int getId() {
return id;
      }
    public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
    }
     public String getName() {
return name;
      }
       public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }
       }
```

**addUser.jsp**

```
  <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
  <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
   <html>
    <head>
<title>Add New User Form</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <f:view>
      <p>
     <h:message id="errors" for="User_Id"></h:message>
      </p>
       <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid border="1" columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="ID"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText id="User_ID" value="#{userBean.id}" required="true">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="500"></f:validateLongRange>
       </h:inputText>

   <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}"></h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton action="#{userBean.addUser}" value="Add Customer">                   </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
   </h:form>
   </f:view>
     </html>
```

**ListUser.jsp**

```
   <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
   <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>List of Users</title>
    </head>
      <body>
      <f:view>
      <h:form>
       <h:outputText value="User #{userBean.name} is added succesfully"> </h:outputText>
      </h:form>

      </f:view>
      </body>
      </html>
```

This is the example done from follwoing link

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-creating-javaserver-faces-jsf-application-in-eclipse-jsf-project-jsf-tutorial/

But some how i am unable to deploy it on jboss.

Comment: You say to use JSF 2.16 (AFAIK we're in JSF 2.2.x version, unless you come from the future) but your faces-config.xml file relates to JSF 1.2.

Comment: What errors are you getting in server logs ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i mean 2.1.6

Comment: @Jay - i dont see anything in the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using JSF 2.1 implementation but you have configured your faces-config.xml file to old JSF 1.2:

```xml
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">
             ^here's the main problem
```

Just update your faces-config.xml file to the right version of JSF:

```xml
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
```

Or even better, just remove it and add it **only** if you're going to use any specific configuration like registering a phase listener. You can find more use cases for this file here: [What is the use of faces-config.xml in JSF 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7583038/1065197).

Apart of this, there are other main issues:

- JSF 2.x requires at least Servlet 2.5, which is available since JBoss 5. Refer to [StackOverflow JSF wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) for more info on this topic.
- The current tutorial you're following refers to JSF 1.2, which is pretty old. JSF 2.0 has been released since 2009. I would recommend stop following this tutorial and move to a newer one like [mkyong's tutorial on JSF 2](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/).

If you really want to stick to JSF 1.2 for specific requirements like maintenance of legacy applications, then replace the JSF libraries from 2.1 to 1.2.