# Error: "schemaLocation value *** must have even number of URI's." on namespaces in spring dispatcher

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, xsd

I was getting following error

```
<Ignored XML validation warning> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 55;
SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx' must have even number of URI's.
```

and my dispatcher servlet was having following namespaces

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
```

and i replaced all above by following

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
```

And my error got disappeared.
How it happened can any one tell??

Answer (score 74):

The `schemaLocation` attribute references an XML Schema document for a namespace.

Basically when you type:

```
xmlns:expns="http://www.example.com"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com
                    http://www.example.com/schema/example.xsd"
```

You are saying: **"*I'm going to use the prefix* `expns` *for the elements of the namespace* `http://www.example.com`*. Also, so you can validate those elements, get the XSD Schema file for* `http://www.example.com` *in* `http://www.example.com/schema/example.xsd`"**

So, in other words, the format is:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="namespace-a   where_to_get_the_xsd_for_namespace-a
                    namespace-b   where_to_get_the_xsd_for_namespace-b
                    namespace-c   where_to_get_the_xsd_for_namespace-c"
```

And so on.

That's why it must me an **even** number.

More info and examples can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256100.aspx).

Comment: So how do you fix this problem?   Do you just remove the `xsi:schemaLocation` that isn't formatted correctly because it isn't actually currently doing anything?   Do you figure out what the namespace should be?   If so, how?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You can either fix (add the counterpart to) the entry in the `xsi:schemaLocation` that is making it uneven, or, if you don't know the correct value for the conterpart, remove the entry (so no need to remove the whole  `xsi:schemaLocation`, though that would work as well, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

@acdcjunior explanation is correct and to resolve the OP's issue, the schemaLocation for the namespace p which is missing needs to be added

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/p http://www.springframework.org/schema/xx-xx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
```

On a further note this warning also occurs if the order of namespace definitions and schemaLocation definitions are different