# Error: No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem with this xml file as said in the title.
I dont know how to solve the problem as i have already searched a lot and only found answers like use clean or change validation of this type to ignore
none of the above worked as i want to clear this problem so that my R will be generet in the gen folder.

Hope someone can see the problem soon as this is my examprojekt im working on and cant get further without solving this error :)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Dekrypter" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you have <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> declared at the very top of your file?

Comment: now i have
It did solve that problem but now the same error is at the new text i just implemented 

this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: there is a difference between errors and warnings (red and yellow). If you are using eclipse try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I found another problem which wasnt listet in the error messages which when solved fixed everything :P and thx

Comment: good (Y). happy coding :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551783/no-grammar-constraints-dtd-or-xml-schema-detected-for-the-document)

Answer (score 4):

Start your XML with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to put on the top of xml this code. It identify the type of the document to encode!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
```

Revalidate the project!

CIAO!!!

Answer (score 1):

I retrieve a solution from a bug issue :

1. Click Window > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Validation
2. Change the setting 'validating files'>'No grammar specified' from warning to ignore.
3. Re-validate your project. No more warnings now.

It works for me.

Comment: If you set the DOCTYPE the validation will be ok. No need to disable validations.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I don't want to add DOCTYPE everywhere just because eclipse feels I should.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

To the top of your XML file. This tells the parser that your file is indeed an XML, that it should use XML version 1.0, and that you are using utf-8 encoding.

Without it, the parser doesn't know how it should parse your XML.

Comment: thx for the explenation but as i wrote to the other comment it just made another problem :(
you know a reason for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

First put this :
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>`
and after that do this structure:
Click Window > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Validation
    Change the setting 'validating files'>'No grammar specified' from warning to ignore.
    Re-validate your project. No more warnings now.
thank you AntoineP and TecnoHelp83 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19314230/3117196
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22973854/3117196
worked as well