# No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document

Tags: android

when working in Eclipse on my app, it shows me in AndroidManifest.XML this at the very beginning:

```
"No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the 
 document."
```

Existing threads only refer to "detected", instead of "referenced".
Is there a difference?
What's the whole point of this?

Comment: Did you try [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=No+grammar+constraints+(DTD+or+XML+Schema)+referenced+in+the+document.&oq=No+grammar+constraints+(DTD+or+XML+Schema)+referenced+in+the+document.&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.910j0j7&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) this error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361912/no-grammar-constraints-dtd-or-xml-schema-detected-for-the-document-android)

Comment: you can do setting to in your eclipse to avoid this error Romana.

Comment: Hi, yeah of course I googled it. All results that come up for me are regarding the "detected". I read about detected, but didn't find anything for "referenced". Maybe it's it the same thing, I thaught, but I don't know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551783/no-grammar-constraints-dtd-or-xml-schema-detected-for-the-document)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start your XML with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why RelativeLayout in Doctype ? The OP is having problem in AndroidManifest.XML . oO ?

Comment: if the problem from `AndroidManifest.XML` then remove the `<!DOCTYPE RelativeLayout>` , this example provided for layouts coz most of people fail with it

Comment: I added <!DOCTYPE RelativeLayout> in my layout file still its showing red circle error icon. what to do ?

Comment: This worked for me in Eclipse 3.7.1: Go to the Preferences window, then XML -> XML Files -> Validation. Then in the Validating files section of the preferences panel on the right, choose Ignore in the drop down box for the "No grammar specified" preference. You may need to close the file and then reopen it to make the warning go away.